# No module error when running spark-submit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I'm submitting a python file which depends on custom modules to run. The file I'm trying to submit is located at project/main.py and our modules are located at project/modules/module1.py. I'm submitting to Yarn in client mode and receiving the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules.module1'
```

The import statement in main.py:

```
from modules import module1.py
```

I have tried zipping the modules folder and passing it to --py-files:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --queue OurQueue --py-files hdfs://HOST/path/to/modules.zip
--conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/hadoop/anaconda3.6/bin/python3"
--conf "spark.pyspark.python=/hadoop/anaconda3.6/bin/python3"
main.py
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a zip file made as

```
zip -r modules
```

I think that you are missing to attach this file to spark context, you can use addPyFile() function in the script as

```
  sc.addPyFile("modules.zip")
```

**Also**, Dont forget to make make empty `__init__.py` file at root level in your directory(modules.zip) like `modules/__init__.py` )

Now to Import, I think you can import it as

```
 from modules.module1 import *
```

or

```
 from modules.module1 import module1
```

**Updated**, Now run the spark-submit command as

```
spark-submit --master yarn --queue OurQueue --py-files modules.zip
--conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/hadoop/anaconda3.6/bin/python3"
--conf "spark.pyspark.python=/hadoop/anaconda3.6/bin/python3"
main.py
```

Comment: I've just added sc.addPyFile, but I'm still getting the same error. The __init__.py files are there.

Comment: is it init or `__init__.py` as i descrbed?

Comment: It is `__init__.py` as you described

Comment: Can you show the content of module1 file? and also is error changed noW?

Comment: I have edited the importing file,can you try it please and let me know that if there is any valid function / object named module1 in module1.py? (I have also updated the spark-submit command and removed hdfs path)

Comment: I've made the suggested changes to both spark-submit and the importing file. The error is now `ImportError: cannot import name 'module1'`.

Comment: Can you show the coneent of module1.py? do you really have a function/class named mdoule1 in module1.py? (also what happens with ` from modules.module1 import *
`)?

Comment: After checking to make sure it was really there, I found that my zip command was missing the -r flag and as such the zip file was empty. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, i assumed that zip is mad e correctly , my bad, I have added it to the answer, feel free to accept and upvote if it helped :)